# creating XQuery project in eclipse

Tags: xslt, xquery, marklogic

I have just started leaning and working on xquery with java. I have a quick question regarding MarkLogic server. I have just installed XQDT for my eclipse, and I needed to configure an interpreter for the XQuery projects, at this point I had two options, the first was `java XQuery engine` and the second was `MarkLogic server`. I tried the `MarkLogic server` first but I couldn't use it, the problem was that it couldn't be connected using localhost:8000 . So, I just used `java XQuery engine`and for this I downloaded `MXQuery` and it worked fine.

the question is that does `MarkLogic server` actually works on `Windoes 7` or it just works on the windows servers ? 
if I just contiue using `MXQuery` can I create any xquery project with having no problems?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MarkLogic Server (the product) works fine on Windows 7.  It comes with a MarkLogic app server running on port 8000 - probably not the one you want to use for debugging.  You should set up another MarkLogic appserver on another port for developing your app (see this [tutorial](http://community.marklogic.com/learn/get-started-apps-2%20%29) for how to set this up or read the product [getting started guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/xml/gs/procedures.xml#22010) )

Once you have that set up, hyou should be able to use the 'MarkLogic Server' engine iff you've managed to install XQDT as described [here](http://community.marklogic.com/learn/xqdt-setup).